# What does it mean that the current returns through the ground?

Tags: electric-circuits

What does it mean that the current returns through the ground? I mean, the current comes from the transformers to our house and then back through "ground".So if you return by "land" to complete the circuit. Is there a way to "intercept" this circuit or worse still is there the possibility of an accident?

Comment: Your question is vague as is. Please provide a link or reference to someone using langauge about current "returning through the ground" in a residential setting. The fault is not entirely your own, many people are confused about grounding and use confusing or wrong terminology. It is difficult to answer your question without more detail about the phrasing you are considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "returning to the ground" or "return by land" as such, since for current to flow, all you need is a potential *difference* and current will flow through the circuit, from one point to another of lower electrical potential.

The term *ground* simply refers to a reference point where the potential is taken to be zero (usually, but you can choose a number other than zero). Voltages are then measured relative to this reference point.

Originally (and commonly these days), in just about all of home and building wiring and electricity, the term “ground” referred to the actual physical earth, which is at a relatively constant potential. In this case, electrical cabling was physically connected to a rod that is pushed into the earth.

But nowadays, as pointed out in the comment by Jageber, the term “ground” is used in a lot of electrical appliances and products, even though they have no physical connection to the earth/ground. For example, if you look at the circuit diagrams (or even the circuit board) of your mobile phone or tablet device, you may find the term “ground” appear.

The possibility of harm from household devices or overhead cables etc., arises when a live wire finds path to the ground through your body (if you touch a live wire or electrified part of a device while another part of you touches the ground or wire/part connected to ground).

Comment: So, could it be said that we are constantly charging the earth with these systems without a neutral (wire)? (Although in reality, the Earth, being very large, "does not charge")